# Get value from a select option and echo content in the header in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

In my Theme Options I am allowing users to set page for the 404 template. (which means they can create any normal page and choose that page as the 404 Template). For this I added the page dropdown using `wp_dropdown_pages()`.

Now I want `echo noindex,nofollow` meta values to the page that the user will choose for the obvious SEO reasons. I tried with this but it does not work.

```
function noindex_404(){
    global $post;
    $option = $_POST['404_id'];
    // $post_val = '2';

    if ($post->ID == $option){
    //if ($post->ID == $post_val)
    // if I try with the direct post value, it's working     
    echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">';
    }
}

add_action('wp_head', 'noindex_404', 1);
```

The following is the HTML created by `wp_dropdown_pages()` and Page 2 is selected under the option name of `404_id` with the option value of **2**

```
<select name="404_id" id="404">
    <option value="1">Page 1</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Page 2</option>
    <option value="3">Page 3</option>
    <option value="4">Page 4</option>
    <option value="5">Page 5</option>   
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check your 404 page using this condition.

```
if ( is_404() ) {
echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">';
}
```

In this case you are not bound to any specific page. what ever the page is used for 404 this function will check if it is 404 page then your code will be echo out otherwise not. 
cheers!

Comment: True and thanks for your answer. I have this already in place for the 404 template output but what about the page I created? Lets say I created a normal page with the name of 404 template and published this. Now this page will be used for the 404 but still it's a published page and it will be indexed as well unless we hide this from search engines using other SEO plugins. Hope I made sense. Thanks once again

Comment: You can also target page ID by using get_post( id )  function. and apply condtion for your specific page ID or you can also add multiple pages in this condition.
And If it's really helps you and my answer is true then plz mark tick on this and you can give up vote too :) 
Thanks